# Xamarin app works on emulator but not on device

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I´ve done a simple app which convert an amount of Bitcoins to a currency.

The app works fine on my android emulator(Nexus 5x).
My problem is that the app throws:

> System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format

When I test it on my android device.
I´ve debuged both my emulator and device and it´s no diffrence in the parameters.

Do someone have any thought why this exception occurs?

[image: stringRate parameter]

```
public static async Task<decimal> ConvertCurrency(string curr, decimal amount)
    {
        var currency = await GetCurrency(curr);
        var stringRate = currency.Rate;
        var rate = decimal.Parse(stringRate);//this is where the it crash
        var result = rate * amount;
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: your device and your emulator are using a different system locale setting

Comment: yeah, its works fine in the emulator.

Comment: This should work: `decimal d = decimal.Parse(stringRate, NumberStyles.Currency, new CultureInfo("en-Us").NumberFormat);`

Comment: @FelixD. worked perfect, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That comma delimiter is your problem. You would need to change your parse Method to detect the Current culture and parse using that `IFormatProvider`

Use the overload(s) of [`decimal.Parse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t7xswkc6(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
string stringRate = "118,130.4542";
decimal d = decimal.Parse(stringRate, 
                          NumberStyles.Currency, 
                          new CultureInfo("en-Us").NumberFormat);
//Output: 118130.4542M

d = decimal.Parse(stringRate, new CultureInfo("en-Us").NumberFormat);
//Output: 118130.4542M
```

Answer (score 1):

Most likely that happens because of the language settings on your phone. If you try to parse a string from the web using default decimal.Pars function, it would try to identify the separator based on your language settings (or local, it depends). That mean that if a phone use a "," as a decimal separator, it would try to look for it into input string even if the string come in a format 12.32. To fix that, pass a culture or implicit separator into parser.

```
decimal.TryParse(EnglishDecimal, out b)
```